# How to add friends on Ultranet?

Tags: blog

My Government Primary school where I am a student, has just given us [Ultranet](https://ultranet.vic.edu.au) and I was wondering how do I add friends on it so that I can see their blog posts and their wall or just at least see their blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a very localized question. However, I found [this how to manual](http://issuu.com/dmgregg/docs/how_to_guides), that explains different actions. Regarding your needs, you might want to take a look at [page 34](http://image.issuu.com/100524211502-249a2e6e14dd40c4ade3ca1e28defa84/jpg/page_34.jpg) and [page 36](http://image.issuu.com/100524211502-249a2e6e14dd40c4ade3ca1e28defa84/jpg/page_36.jpg).

Not having access to the service, I can't verify if the info is correct or not, so you'll just have to test it on your own.